# Matplotlib function animation not animating for pre-calculated data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am working on some animated scatter plots in python with matplotlib. I currently have this code:

```
def calulateStep():

    # Math stuff ....
    # Changes values in in 'circpos' Nx2 array
   

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.set(xlim=(-WELLRADIUS,WELLRADIUS), ylim=(-WELLRADIUS,WELLRADIUS))

[x,y] = np.hsplit(circpos,2)

scat = ax.scatter(x.flatten(),y.flatten())

def animate(i):
    calculateStep()
    scat.set_offsets(circpos)
    return scat,
    
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=60)

anim.save('test2.gif',writer='imagemagick')

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

The function calculateStep calculates new x,y values for the scatter. `circpos` contains the data array at each step. this works well and produces an animated gif ofthe scatter plot as expected. However the function is a rather slow numerical calculation and many many steps are required to produce stable output, so I would rather calculate all before and then animate only select frames. So I tried this.

```
results = [circpos]

for h in range(61):
    
    calculateStep()
    results.append(circpos)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.set(xlim=(-WELLRADIUS,WELLRADIUS), ylim=(-WELLRADIUS,WELLRADIUS))

[x,y] = np.hsplit(results[0],2)

scat = ax.scatter(x.flatten(),y.flatten())


def animate(i):

    scat.set_offsets(results.pop(0))
    return scat,
    
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=60)

anim.save('test2.gif',writer='imagemagick')

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

However with this method the generated gif contains only the final frame of the animation. If I print the data from within the animate function I find that the correct numerical values are being popped from the results list but for some reason only the final value is there in the gif. I have also tried using `results[i]` rather than `results.pop(0)` I am at a loss to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I solved my own problem. When I add each iteration of the global array circpos to the results list, it is of course a shallow copy. Meaning it's just a reference to the original circpos array. So I end up with a list full of references to the same object. The print out was just me misinterpreting what I was looking at.
Instead I now add circpos.copy() to my list to get new copies of the array at each step.
This has tripped me up in Python before I realize. Still learning!